# How to make a window border for a circle object in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I wrote a small football game. It has a player (circle) controlled with the arrows, a ball (also circle) and two goals on the left and on the right side (rects). Until now it was made if I go over the screen the player and the ball appear on the other side. I now need to set a window border: If the ball (and the player go near the border they can't escape the window. For the ball a collision is a possibility too. I tried different things, but they didn't work.

here's some of the things I tried:

```
def checkballborder():
global ballX
global ballY

if  ballX  >  windowsize[0]:
    ballX *= -1
    
if  ballX  <  windowsize[0]:
    ballX *= -1


if  ballY  >  windowsize[1]:
    ballY *= -1
    
if  ballY  <  windowsize[0]:
    ballY *= -1
```

and:

```
#borders
if  ballX < ballradius:
    ballX = ballradius

if  ballX > windowsize[0] - ballradius:
    ballX = windowsize[0] - ballradius


if  ballY > ballradius:
    ballY = ballradius

if  ballY > windowsize[1] - ballradius:
    ballY = windowsize[1] - ballradius
```

here's my whole code:

```
import pygame, time, sys, math, random

pygame.init()

#Farben bestimmen
red = pygame.color.Color("red")
blue = pygame.color.Color("blue")
white = pygame.color.Color("white")
black = pygame.color.Color("black")
green = pygame.color.Color("green")
beige = pygame.color.Color("#F5F5DC")

#Fenster
width = 200
height = 200
windowsize = [width, height]
fps = 60
window = pygame.display.set_mode (windowsize)



#Uhr
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Position Spieler
playerX = random.randrange (0, windowsize[0])
playerY = random.randrange (0, windowsize[1])

#Position Ball
ballX = random.randrange(0, windowsize[0])
ballY = random.randrange(0, windowsize[1])
ballradius = 6
#Mittellinie
midlineA = int (windowsize [0] / 2)
midlineB = int (windowsize [0] / 2)
#Anstoßkreiß 
midcircleX = int (windowsize[0] / 2)
midcircleY = int (windowsize[1] / 2)
#Position Tor links
lgoalX = 0
lgoalY = int (windowsize [1] / 2 - 10)
lgoalW = 15
lgoalH = 25

#Position Tor rechts
rgoalX = int (windowsize [0] - 15)
rgoalY = int (windowsize [1] / 2 - 10)
rgoalW = 15
rgoalH = 25

def checkOffWindowX(playerX) :
    return playerX % windowsize[0]

def checkOffWindowY(playerY):
    return playerY % windowsize[1]

    

        
def checkTouching():
    global playerX
    global ballX
    global playerY
    global ballY
    if -10 < playerY - ballY < 10 and -10 < playerX - ballX < 10:
        xDiff = playerX - ballX
        yDiff = playerY - ballY
        #Spielball verschieben
        ballX -= xDiff *2
        ballY -= yDiff *2
        #Falls der Spielball in einer Ecke sein sollte
        if   ballY == 0:
             xDiff -= 5
        elif ballX == windowsize[0]:
             xDiff += 5
        if   ballY == windowsize[1]:
             yDiff += 5
        elif ballY == windowsize[1]:
             yDiff +=5

       

    
        
            

done = False
while not done:
    window.fill(green)
    #Bewegung Spieler
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys [pygame.K_UP]:
        playerY -= 1
    if keys [pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerY += 1
    if keys [pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX += 1
    #Positionsbestimmung
    playerX = checkOffWindowX(playerX)
    playerY = checkOffWindowY(playerY)

    #Auf Berührung testen
    checkTouching()


    #borders
    if  ballX < ballradius:
        ballX = ballradius

    if  ballX > windowsize[0] - ballradius:
        ballX = windowsize[0] - ballradius


    if  ballY > ballradius:
        ballY = ballradius

    if  ballY > windowsize[1] - ballradius:
        ballY = windowsize[1] - ballradius

    

    
    
    #Anstoßkreis zeichnen
    pygame.draw.circle (window, white, [midcircleX,midcircleY], 20, 3)
    #Mittelpunkt zeichnen
    pygame.draw.circle (window, white, [midcircleX,midcircleY], 5)
    #Mittellinie zeichnen
    pygame.draw.line (window, white, (midlineA , 0), (midlineB,200),4)
    #Spieler zeichnen
    pygame.draw.circle (window, red, [playerX, playerY], 8)  
    #Spielball zeichnen
    pygame.draw.circle (window, blue, [ballX,ballY], ballradius)

    

#####~Toren zeichnen und Torerkennung~#######################################
                                                                            #
    #Tor links zeichnen                                                     #
    pygame.draw.rect(window, white, (lgoalX, lgoalY, lgoalW, lgoalH))       #
    #Tor rechts zeichnen                                                    #
    pygame.draw.rect(window, white, (rgoalX, rgoalY, rgoalW, rgoalH))       #
                                                                            #
                                                                            #
    #Rechte Tor                                                             #
    distancer = int(math.hypot(ballX - rgoalX, ballY - rgoalY))             #
    #Linke Tor                                                              #
    distancel = int(math.hypot(ballX - lgoalX, ballY - lgoalY))             #
                                                                            #
    if  distancer < 20 >= 0:                                                #
        done = True                                                         #
    if  distancel < 20 >= 0:                                                #
        done = True                                                         #
                                                                            #
    #if  ballX < ballradius:                                                #
    #    ballX = ballradius                                                 #
                                                                            #
    #if  ballY < ballradius:                                                #
     #   ballY = ballradius                                                 #
                                                                            #
#############################################################################    
        
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

pygame.quit()
```

the comments are in german, but if you need something, I can translate it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object for the bounding box of the object and [`clamp_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) to keep the object in bounds:

For instance:

```py
def ClampToRect(x, y, radius, border_rect):
    
    # define a rectangle by the center of the object and the radius 
    object_rect = pygame.Rect(x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
    
    # "clamp" to border 
    #     move the rectangle inside the border rectangle
    #     if the rectangle is not completely inside
    object_rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
    
    # return the new center point of the rectnagle
    return object_rect.center
```

```py
window = pygame.display.set_mode(windowsize)

# [...]

done = False
while not done:
    # [...]

    # playerX = checkOffWindowX(playerX)
    # playerY = checkOffWindowY(playerY)

    player_radius = 8
    playerX, playerY = ClampToRect(playerX, playerY, player_radius, window.get_rect())

    # [...]
```

Do the same for the ball

```py
def checkTouching():
    global playerX
    global ballX
    global playerY
    global ballY
    if -10 < playerY - ballY < 10 and -10 < playerX - ballX < 10:
        xDiff = playerX - ballX
        yDiff = playerY - ballY
        #Spielball verschieben
        ballX -= xDiff *2
        ballY -= yDiff *2
        ballX, ballY = ClampToRect(ballX, ballY, ballradius, window.get_rect())
```

Comment: but the player and the ball are both circles, not rects

Comment: I got this:  ball = pygame.Rect([ballX,ballY], ballradius)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Comment: I thought in def ClampToRect(x, y, radius, rect): 'rect' needed to be defined before. What am I missing on ?

Comment: I already read your answer, but I don't quite understand it. What do you exacly mean by border surface is it the window or is it something else I need to pre define ?

Comment: It works now thanks. I'll do the same for my player